# Поиск по MIME-типу файла

Tags: ubuntu, bash

Как посредством bash найти все файлы на компьютере по MIME-типу, например видео?

Comment: http://txt.binnyva.com/2009/05/find-files-of-a-specific-mime-type/

Comment: ещё вариант: `$ find /где/искать -type f -exec sh -c "file -b --mime-type \"{}\" | grep -q '^video'" \; -print`

Comment: связанный вопрос [Locate files matching mimetype in a directory recursively via command line](https://askubuntu.com/q/522476/3712)

Comment: Поставить что-то типа tracker, и читать его БД.

Answer (score 1):

Мне помогло решение предложенное в [комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/706160/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be-mime-%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%83-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0/1126985#comment1051644_706160). Так искала изображения:

```sh
~$ find tmp/ -type f -exec sh -c "file -b --mime-type \"{}\"|grep -q '^image'" \; -print
tmp/Lxхх984.png
```